# sqlalchemy adjacency list - ошибка

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Здраствуйте, делаю вроде все по доке, но ловлю эксепшн что нет внешнего ключа. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело?

```
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'SC84'
    id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
    parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey('sku.id'))
    parent = relationship('Sku', foreign_keys='Sku.parent_code')
    ...
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Sku.parent - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# нужно указать поле без имени класса и все заработает.
# правда в моем случае нужно было еще использовать связь не один ко многим и 
# многие к одному. 
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'SC84'
    id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
    parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey(id))
    parent = relationship('Sku', foreign_keys=parent_code)
```

Answer (score -1):

Привожу пример работы с внешними ключами:

```
class Datasets(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dataset'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dataset = Column(String(255), default='', index=True)
    title = Column(String(255), default='', index=True)
    description = Column(UnicodeText, default='')

class DatasetToPerson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dataset2person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dataset_id = Column(
        Integer(),
        ForeignKey('dataset.id'),
        index=True,
        nullable=False
    )
    condition = Column(Integer, index=True)
    probability = Column(Integer, index=True)
```

Comment: У меня подобных случаев на 1000 строк кода и все работает, проблема конкретно с adjacency list (парент на себя)